# Как применить одну функцию onclick к нескольким кнопкам?

Tags: javascript, pug

У меня есть список кнопок в сайдбаре и два поля ввода(номер один и номер два) в главном контейнере. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на первую(или вторую, третью и т.д.) кнопку имя этой кнопки отправилось на главный контейнер в поле ввода номер один. Затем при нажатии на вторую(или первую, или третью и т.д.) кнопку имя этой кнопки отправилось на главный контейнер в поле ввода номер два. 
Я думаю, что я должен это сделать с помощью события onclick, но для меня способ реализации не имеет большого значения. 
Ниже приведу свой код, который отправляет имя нажатой кнопки только в первое поле ввода(поле номер один).

JS

```
function projectClick(index, name) {
  const nameA = document.getElementById('prjA');
  const nameB = document.getElementById('prjB');   
  nameA.value = name;
}
```

pug

```
mixin projectButton(objectName index) 
  lable
    input.prjBtn(type="button" value=`${objectKey}` onclick="projectClick('" + index + "','" + objectKey + "')")

block append main
  form.formMod
    input.form-control#prjA(type="text" name="prjA")
    input.form-control#prjB(type="text" name="prjB")

block append sidebar
  form.formMod
    each val, index in projectlist
      +projectButton(val.objectKey, index)
```

Comment: А если уже два поля заполнены, и потом кликнуть на 3ю кнопку. Что произойдет?

Comment: а в чем смысл в случае одного обработчика на нескольких кнопках, почему например не ловить событие на контейнере в котором расположены эти кнопки?

Comment: приведите в вопросе ссылку на codepen с той разметкой которая у вас есть, постараюсь помочь...

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать если пройтись циклом по элементам и повесить на них эвент onClick.
Например так

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');
for(let i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
  const btn = buttons[i]; 
  btn.addEventListener('click' , (e) => projectClick(i , e.target.value))
}
```

Comment: а почему  для итерации не использовать `forEach` вместо `for`?

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk [рабочий пример](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drmXrp?editors=1010)